# Atualizar uma tabela sem refresh de pagina

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tabela-html, atualização

vi aqui várias respostas para perguntas semelhantes à minha, mas nenhuma resolveu meu problema. Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro de itens que ao clicar no botão inserir ele vai dar o insert no banco, limpar o input e por fim mostrar esse item numa tabela abaixo desse form-inline de inserção de itens. Já consigo dar o insert no banco pelo submit, já consigo dar o reset nos campos de input. Meu único problema é que para esse item cadastrado aparecer na tabela preciso dar um refresh completo na página. Isso irá demandar muito tempo do usuário. Alguém consegue me ajudar a entender o que estou fazendo de errado?

Vou colocar os códigos HTML e JS abaixo. Muito obrigado!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">

<title>Solicitação de Produto Indisponível</title>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="respostas.php">PED Peças</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="respostas.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Solicitações de Compra
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="Projeto001.php">Nova Solicitação</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="respostas.php">Solicitações Realizadas</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="listaprecos.php">Respostas dos Fornecedores</a>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>


        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Sair</button>

    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid pt-2">
    <h4>Solicitação de Produto Indisponível - <?php echo utf8_encode($info_solicitacoes['status_solicitacao']); ?> </h4>
</div>

<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group form-control-sm col-sm-1">
        <label for="id_solicitacao">Nº Solicitação</label>
        <input readonly name="id_solicitacao" type="number" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["id_solicitacao"]; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="codcliente" placeholder="Cód. Int.">
    </div>



    <div class="form-group form-control-sm col-sm-1">
        <label for="codcliente">Cód. Cliente</label>
        <input type="number" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["cod_cliente"]; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="codcliente" placeholder="Cód. Int.">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-control-sm col-sm-3">
        <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
        <input style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["cliente"]; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cliente" placeholder="Cliente">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-control-sm col-md-2">
        <label for="tel">Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["telefone"]; ?>" class="form-control-sm form-control" id="tel" placeholder="(XX) XXXX-XXXX">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="contato">Contato</label>
        <input style="text-transform: uppercase" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["contato"]; ?>" type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" id="contato" placeholder="Contato">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="vendedor">Vendedor</label>
        <input style="text-transform: uppercase" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["vendedor"]; ?>" type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" id="vendedor" placeholder="Vendedor">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-control-sm mb-5">
        <label for="obs">Observação</label>
        <input style="text-transform: uppercase" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["observacao"]; ?>" type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" id="obs" placeholder="Observação">
    </div>


    <a href="../paginas/respostas.php"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Voltar</button></a>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" hidden>Atualizar</button>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h4>Inserir Itens Para Cotação</h4>


    <form id="insere_itens">

        <input hidden readonly name="id_solicitacao" type="number" value="<?php echo $info_solicitacoes["id_solicitacao"]; ?>" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="codcliente" placeholder="Cód. Int.">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-1 container-fluid">
                <label for="codint">Cód. Int.</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="codint" id="codint" placeholder="Cód. Int.">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="numorig">Número Original</label>
                <input style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" class="form-control" name="numorig" id="numorig" placeholder="Número Original">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="codfabr">Código Fabricante</label>
                <input style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" class="form-control" name="codfabr" id="codfabr" placeholder="Código Fabricante">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <label for="marca">Marca</label>
                <input style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" class="form-control" name="marca" id="marca" placeholder="Marca">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="produto">Descrição do Produto</label>
                <input required style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" class="form-control" name="produto" id="produto" placeholder="Descrição do Produto">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <label for="unid">Unidade</label>
                <input required style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" class="form-control" name="unid" id="unid" placeholder="Und.">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                <label for="quant">Quantidade</label>
                <input required style="text-transform: uppercase" type="number" class="form-control" name="quant" id="quant" placeholder="Qtd.">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Inserir" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">

        </div>



    </form>
</div>
<hr>

<table id="tabeladeitens" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cód. Int.</th>
            <th scope="col">Núm. Orig.</th>
            <th scope="col">Cód. Fabr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Marca</th>
            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
            <th scope="col">Und.</th>
            <th scope="col">Qtd.</th>
            <th scope="col">R$ Un.</th>
            <th scope="col">R$ Total</th>
            <th scope="col">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php

    $consulta_itens  = "SELECT * FROM itens_solicitacao WHERE id_solicitacao = $id_solicitacao ORDER BY id_item DESC";
    $operacao_itens = mysqli_query($conecta, $consulta_itens);


    ?>

    <div class="conteudotabela">
        <tbody id="tabela_itens">
        <?php while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($operacao_itens)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $registro["cod_interno"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strtoupper($registro["num_orig"]) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strtoupper($registro["cod_fabric"]) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strtoupper($registro["marca"]) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strtoupper($registro["descricao"]) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strtoupper($registro["und"]) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $registro["qtd"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $registro["venda_unit"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $registro["venda_total"] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Autorizar Compra"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" title="Recusar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    <?php
    }
    mysqli_free_result($operacao_itens);

    ?>
    </div>
</table>



<!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
<!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

E abaixo segue o script JS. Pra atualizar tive que virar com o location.reload por enquanto:

```
<script>
    $('#insere_itens').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formulario = $(this);
        var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario)

        //$('#insere_itens input').val(""); //coloca todos valores de todos inputs do form como vazio
        //$('#insere_itens input[type = submit]').val("Enviar"); //recoloca o texto no botão

    });


    function inserirFormulario(dados) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dados.serialize(),
            url: "../conexoes/inseriritens.php",
            async: false
            //$('#insere_itens input').val(""); //coloca todos valores de todos inputs do form como vazio
            //$('#insere_itens input[type = submit]').val("Enviar");
        }).then(sucesso, falha);

        function sucesso(data) {
            console.log();
            $('#insere_itens')[0].reset();
            $('#tabeladeitens').empty();
            location.reload();
            
            
        }
           


    }
    function falha() {
        console.log("erro");

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Basta fazer um `.append()` ou `.prepend()` na tabela com as informações inseridas no BD.

Comment: No javascript faz uma nova TR com as TD com os dados inseridos na BD e depois fazer um ``.append()`` à tbody da table.

Answer (score -1):

Antes de tudo seria interessante você separar o trecho do código responsável por renderizar a linha da tabela, podemos fazer isso criando uma função no php:

```
function renderTableLine($registro) {
  return <<<HTML
    <tr>
      <td>{$registro["cod_interno"]}</td>
      <td>{mb_strtoupper($registro["num_orig"])}</td>
      <td>{mb_strtoupper($registro["cod_fabric"])}</td>
      <td>{mb_strtoupper($registro["marca"])}</td>
      <td>{mb_strtoupper($registro["descricao"])}</td>
      <td>{mb_strtoupper($registro["und"])}</td>
      <td>{$registro["qtd"]}</td>
      <td>{$registro["venda_unit"]}</td>
      <td>{$registro["venda_total"]}</td>
      <td>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Autorizar Compra"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" title="Recusar"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
HTML;
}
```

Esta função seria usada em dois lugares, primeiro para renderizar todas as linhas da tabela dentro do tbody:

```
<tbody id="tabela_itens">
    <?php while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($operacao_itens)) {
        echo renderTableLine($registro);
    ?>
<tbody>
```

Depois use a mesma função para renderizar a nova linha logo depois de inserir o registro no banco de dados no arquivo inseriritens.php inserindo o mesmo trecho de código logo depois de inserir o registro no banco:

```
echo renderTableLine($registro_inserido);
```

Por fim, faça um append do html gerado na execução do arquivo inseriritens.php no tbody da tabela

```
function inserirFormulario(dados) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dados.serialize(),
            url: "../conexoes/inseriritens.php",
            async: false
        }).then(sucesso, falha);

        function sucesso(data) {
            $('#insere_itens')[0].reset();
            $('#tabeladeitens tbody').append(data);
        }
    }
```

É provável que você tenha que fazer ajustes no código, uma dica é fazer um debug para entender o que está chegando no "data" antes de fazer o append, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: basta no javascript fazer um ``.append()`` a um anova TR com todas as TD com os dados do AJAX. Não precisa ir ao php outra vez

Comment: Isso mesmo, no sucesso faz o append do resultado retornado do POST feito via AJAX.

Comment: Valeu pessoal! Deu certo. Muito obrigado!